# Execution time limit was exceeded c#, while using Math.Pow() in recursion

Tags: c#, recursion

I am trying to print the power of number. but I am getting execution time exceeded error.

```
   using System;


public class Program
{

     public static void Power(int B,int C)
    {
        if(B == 1)
            return;
        double temp = Math.Pow(B,C);
        Console.WriteLine(temp);
        Power(B--,C);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        Power(4,2);
    }
}
```

I am getting this error.

```
Run-time exception (line -1): Execution time limit was exceeded
```

please help me understand the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change this line:

```
Power(B--,C);
```

To

```
Power(--B,C);
```

or

```
B--;
Power(B,C);
```

It is because `B--` sends the value of `B` not `B-1` to the method, before subtracting 1. and this causes infinite loop, B stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have B-- which passes the current value of B through and then subtracts 1.
Instead write --B.